# Preventing crashes if adding an item to a location that doesn't exists in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

My code:

```
public class MultiArr {

    private int row;
    private int col;
    private int MultiA[][];

    public MultiArr(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        MultiA = new int[row][col];
    }

    public void setItem(int row, int col, int item) {
        if (row > MultiA.length || col > MultiA.length) {
            System.out.println("out of bound");
        } else {
            MultiA[row][col] = item;
        }
    }

    public int getItem(int row, int col) {
        return MultiA[row][col];
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return MultiA.length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultiArr test = new MultiArr(1,2);  
        test.setItem(1,0,1);
        //System.out.println(test.getItem(0,0));
        //System.out.println(test.getLength());
    }

}
```

So I create this class to create a 2d array of ints (for testing purposes) and it works for the most part
but the problem I'm facing is when you try to add an item to a location which doesnt
exists, for examples:

Suppose you say:

```
MultiArr test = new MultiArr(2,2);
```

This creates:

```
  _01_
0 |XX
1 |XX
```

And now suppose you want to set the value 1 at postion (0, 1):

```
test.setItem(0,1,1);
```

This works, but however when you try to put in a position that doesnt exist
it will crash, for example:

```
test.setItem(3,2,1);

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at mazegame.MultiArr.setItem(MultiArr.java:19)
    at mazegame.MultiArr.main(MultiArr.java:33)
```

To solve this what I did was well if you put in a number for row and its higher then the 
number of row you created or if you put in a number for column and its higher than
the number you put when you created the array than it should crash, so for this I put and
if-else to take care of that situation.

But then theres a another problem and thats if you end up with like multiple rows and 1 column

Example:

```
MultiArr test = new MultiArr(1,2);

  _0 1
0 |X X

test.setItem(1,0,1);
```

This now crashed because that location doesnt exists and so it skips the if-else that I put to try to prevent the previous error.

I have been stuck of this for a while now and I was wondering if anyone knows a better and easier way to prevent it from crashing if the location doesn't exist, thanks for anyone that helps :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a good idea to handle this by printing a message. Trying to set a value to an element of an array that doesn't exist is an error of programming and the program should not be able to continue its execution after this. However, if you really want to do it, you must change

```
 if (row > MultiA.length || col > MultiA.length)
```

with

```
 if (row >= MultiA.length || col >= MultiA[row].length)
```

Indeed, don't forget that an array `arr` is indexed from `0` to `arr.length - 1`, so `arr.length` is also an invalid index (that's why so need a `>=` rather than a `>`. Finally, the other thing you had wrong was that you didn't take in account the number of columns but the number of rows (`MultiA.length`) in both parts of the test.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if (row > MultiA.length || col > MultiA.length) {
```

With

```
if (row > MultiA.length || col > MultiA[row].length) {
```

`MultiA.length` only gets the length of the array. `MultiA` is an array of arrays though. You want to get the length of the array inside.

Also, as [Alexander Zhak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2653775/alexander-zhak) said, the `>` should be a `>=`, because arrays in Java start at index 0 and go to `length-1`.

Comment: Thank you Anubian for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays start counting at 0, so an array `new int[1][2];` has the valid locations `{0, 0}` and `{0, 1}`, so you should adjust your code to

```
if (row >= MultiA.length || col >= MultiA[row].length) {
```

Comment: Thank you Smutje for the help!